# Drupal: How can I automatically send an email to an user when I unblock him (status becomes active)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I automatically send an email to an user when I unblock him (status becomes active) ?

I've searched the appropriate rule, but I couldn't find the correct condition (there is not a token with the user "status" or "block / unblock" property.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add event: User account details have been updated
Add condition "Execute custom PHP code", write there code:

```
return !$account_unchanged->status && $account->status;
```

Add your action about sending email.

Comment: For some reason I don't have the "Execute custom PHP code". Check the following 3 screenshots: (1) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/Screen%20shot%202011-02-16%20at%201.53.47%20PM.png (2) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/Screen%20shot%202011-02-16%20at%201.53.32%20PM.png (3) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/Screen%20shot%202011-02-16%20at%201.56.04%20PM.png

Comment: Please enable PHP filter module, it's drupal distr.module.